# Can we perform some action whenever crash occurs in android

Tags: android

I want to perform implicit logout of my app when ever my app gets crash. So that when user does login again so that he will be having fresh data instead of incomplete data that was caused by my crash.

Comment: An ANR is not a crash. Here is a description about what an ANR is http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Comment: Fixed the title, replaced "ANR" with "crash"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register your `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` on each thread that can crash. This will allow you to add some extra steps before crash is reported to Android. But be careful, because if your code throws another exception during those steps, you will never receive crash report to your Android Market account.

Basically, keep code inside your uncaught exception handler as simple as possible.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;

    MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(){
        defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        //TODO: add your custom code here
        defaultHandler.uncaughtException(t,e);
    }  
}
```

Comment: If he was looking for an ANR as the title suggested, this would not help. But he is probably looking for exactly what you posted.

Comment: @Mike dg, thanks for clarification. I actually was confused by the question title too. But question itself was pretty clear about what he intended to do.